# redux-saga takeEvery only called when you click on btn, componentDidMount doesn`t call action correct

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

Sory for my English!

I am doing test work on React.js. The task is to make a regular blog. I ran into an unwanted problem. As a rule, componentDidMount makes entries, ready data and is called once.
I invoke the loadPosts action in the CDM to get the data.
The takeEvery effect sees the necessary saga, but does not cause it, but skips it.
When I press a button, everything works fine.

I'm new to React. All i tried is google

[repository with project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTFm1.png)
`branch - dev-fullapp`

---

index.js

```
 import store from "./redux/store";

    const app = (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <App />
        </Provider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
```

---

store.js

```
    import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
    import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
    import apiSaga from "./sagas/index";
    import rootReducer from "./reducers/index";

    const initialiseSagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

    const storeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

    const store = createStore(
      rootReducer,
      storeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(initialiseSagaMiddleware))
    );

    initialiseSagaMiddleware.run(apiSaga);
    export default store;
```

---

sagas.js

```
    import { put, call, takeEvery } from "redux-saga/effects";
    import { fetchGetPosts } from "../apis/index";
    import { setErrorPosts, setPosts } from "../actions/actions-posts";

    function* workerGetPosts() {
        try {
            const posts = yield call(fetchGetPosts);
        yield put(setPosts(posts));
      } catch (err) {
            yield put(setErrorPosts(err));
      }
    }

    export default function* watchSaga() {
        yield takeEvery(POSTS.LOADING, workerGetPosts);
    }
```

---

actions.js

```
    import { POSTS } from "../constants";

    export const loadPosts = () => {
        console.log('action-load')
        return {
        type: POSTS.LOADING
        }
    };

    export const setPosts = payload => ({
      type: POSTS.LOAD_SUCCESS,
      payload
    });

    export const setErrorPosts = error => ({
      type: POSTS.ERROR,
      error
    });
```

---

rootReducer.js

```
    import { combineReducers } from "redux";

    import postsReducer from "./reducer-posts";
    import loadReducer from "./reducer-load";

    const rootReducer = combineReducers({
      posts: postsReducer,
      isLoad: loadReducer
    });

    export default rootReducer;
```

---

reducer-posts.js

```
    import { POSTS } from "../constants";

    const postState = {
      posts: []
    };

    function postsReducer(state = postState, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case POSTS.LOAD_SUCCESS:
          return {
            ...state,
            posts: [...action.payload]
          };
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }

    export default postsReducer;
```

---

reducer-load.js

```
    import { POSTS } from "../constants";
    import { combineReducers } from "redux";

    const loadReducerPosts = (state = false, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
            case POSTS.LOADING: return false;
            case POSTS.LOAD_SUCCESS: return true;
        case POSTS.ERROR: return false;
        default: return state;
      }
    };

    const loadReducer = combineReducers({
      isLoadPost: loadReducerPosts,
    });

    export default loadReducer;
```

---

news.jsx

```
    class News extends Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        loadPosts();
      }

      render() {
            CONST { loadPosts }this.props
        return (
          <main>

            // code

            <button onClick={loadPosts}>Test Button</button>
          </main>
        );
      }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (
        { posts: { loading, posts, success } }
    ) => ({
      posts,
      loading,
      success
    });

    export default connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      { loadPosts }
    )(News);
```

---

[image]

Comment: Shouldnt you be calling loadPosts method like this.props.loadPosts() in componentDidMount ?

Comment: @Mobeen Damn, of course. I did not notice such a typo. I decided to dig deeper and forgot about the basics.

Comment: Mind if I put this as answer?

Comment: @Mobeen Yes, ofcourse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loadPosts method is available as props to the React component in current case. Unlike in componentDidMount, on button click you are calling the function from props.  You have to use `this.props.loadPosts()` on both places